# My major and my Masters both rebranded. Should I update my resume?

Tags: resume, degree

I have a BA in Human Services and a Masters of Public Administration with a focus on Science & Technology Policy. Both degree programs have changed their names slightly since I graduated. My undergraduate major is now called Human Services *& Social Justice*, while my grad school specialization is now Science, Technology *& Environmental* Policy. The courses I took still meet the requirements of the renamed programs.

Here's my question. Should I update my resume to use the new names or should I continue using the old names? I want people to be able to Google me and find results that match, but I also want to be accurate about what the degrees were called when I received them.

Comment: Why not use _"OldName/NewName"_ with a subnote on your resume that names have since changed?

Comment: @iLuvLogix I hadn't thought of that possibility

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The new names arguably sound better in both cases, which I guess is why the universities changed them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually the preference is to put in the resume what you can prove: that is, the same name of degree as you have in your certificate.

If the university chose to change the name, you can mention both old and new names in the resume. It does not hurt either way.

Any cosmetic change, causing a difference between the job requirement and the actual (your resume) is expected to be understood by the recruiter / organization you're applying for.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 4):

No, you shouldn't change the names. You can't say for sure that the curriculum is the same in the new course as in the old one, and you've been awarded the old title.

Most Uni awards have some code or reference number. Maybe you can include that for reference.